# reading namespace in XML document using xquery or XSLT v 1.0

Tags: xml, xquery

I need a help on XQuery where I am receiving a XML SOAP envelop body from external system and now I have to route the data based on namespace in XML.

like below

```
<v1:EmployeeResponse xmlns:v1="http://test.service.net/com/v1">
    <v1:Reference>SequenceTime="2019-03-07 12.15.01.970236"</v1:Reference>
    <v1:Details>
        <v1:Name>
            <v1:FirstName>Alex</v1:FirstName>
        </v1:Name>
    </v1:Details>
</v1:EmployeeResponse>
```

here say I am getting namesace as http://test.service.net/com/v1 then i should update a temp variable says v1 and if this is http://test.service.net/com/v2, the variable should be v2.

I am more curious to know how i can read a namespace from the XML document using Xquery or XSLT.

Comment: There is a `namespace-uri` function defined in XPath and therefore also XSLT/XQuery that allows you to read out the namespace of a node in an XML document: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-namespace-uri. I am not sure what you consider a "temp variable" in XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`namespace-uri(/*)` will give you the namespace of the outermost element of the document.